# После смены значения атрибута checked с помощью js и отправки формы в массиве POST отсутствует данное поле

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 cont">
    <b>1. Оцените специалиста</b>
    <div class="input">
        <input class="checked" id="rating5" type="radio" name="rating" value="5" checked="checked">
        <label for="rating5">5 - <small>отлично</small></label>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <input id="rating4" type="radio" name="rating" value="4">
        <label for="rating4">4 - <small>хорошо</small></label>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <input id="rating3" type="radio" name="rating" value="3">
        <label for="rating3">3 - <small>удовлетворительно</small></label>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <input id="rating2" type="radio" name="rating" value="2">
        <label for="rating2">2 - <small>плохо</small></label>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <input id="rating1" type="radio" name="rating" value="1">
        <label for="rating1">1 - <small>очень плохо</small></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('document').ready(function(){

    $('.input input').on('click', function(){           

        var container = $(this).parents('.cont');

        $(container).find('.input input').removeAttr('checked');            

        $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');         

    });
});
```

Если отправляю форму сразу (не переключая радиокнопки), то в массиве POST элемент с ключом rating имеется.

Если переключаюсь на другую радиокнопку, то в исходном коде (в консоли) у выбранного инпута добавляется атрибут checked, но в массиве POST после отправки формы вообще нет ключа.

В чем причина?

Answer (score 0):

Зачем писать событие клика на радио, когда она итак корректно работает? Функция `attr` задает аттрибут, но не меняет значение, для этого нужно использовать `prop`, просто используйте мой пример и удалите ваше событие клика на input.

```js
$(document).on('submit', '#example', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).serializeArray());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="example">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1 cont">
    <b>1. Оцените специалиста</b>
    <div class="input">
      <input class="checked" id="rating5" type="radio" name="rating" value="5" checked="checked">
      <label for="rating5">5 - <small>отлично</small></label>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input id="rating4" type="radio" name="rating" value="4">
      <label for="rating4">4 - <small>хорошо</small></label>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input id="rating3" type="radio" name="rating" value="3">
      <label for="rating3">3 - <small>удовлетворительно</small></label>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input id="rating2" type="radio" name="rating" value="2">
      <label for="rating2">2 - <small>плохо</small></label>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
      <input id="rating1" type="radio" name="rating" value="1">
      <label for="rating1">1 - <small>очень плохо</small></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>
```